# Android - SQLite Exception near "alter" : syntax error (code 1)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_USER + "(" + "id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "username"
        + " TEXT," + "passwort" + " TEXT," + "sportlevel" + " TEXT,"
        + "ziel" + " TEXT," + "alter" + " REAL," + "groesse" + " REAL,"
        + "gewicht" + " REAL," + "zielgewicht" + " REAL,"
        + "koerperfettanteil" + " REAL," + "trainingprowoche" + " REAL"
        + ")";
```

//create table statement for USERs

Comment: ALTER is a **reserved keyword**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify your question by describing your goal, problem and the steps you have tried so far (I guess this is the provided source code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the **alter** as column name in the SQLite because it is already reserved keyword.

See here for reserved keywords : https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 1):

`alter` is a sqlite keyword, I do not think it is usable as column name